# Scrapy doesn`t make POST-requests

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

I write my Scrapy spider which should handle some site with AJAX. In theory it should work OK and moreover it works OK when I use it manually with fetch() in Scrapy shell, but when I run "scrapy crawl ..." I don`t see any POST requests in log and no items are scraped. What can it be and what is the source of the problem?

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy import Request, FormRequest
    import json


class ExpertSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "expert"
    allowed_domains = ["expert.fi"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.expert.fi/',
    )

def parse(self, response):
    categories = response.xpath('//div[@id="categories-navigation"]//a/@href').extract()
    for cat in categories:
        yield Request(response.urljoin(cat), callback=self.parseCat)

def parseCat(self, response):
    catMenu = response.xpath('//div[@id="category-left-menu"]')
    if catMenu:
        subCats = catMenu.xpath('.//a[@class="category"]/@href').extract()
        for subCat in subCats:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(subCat), callback=self.parseCat)
    else:
        self.parseProdPage(response)
        print "I`ve reached this point"  # debug

def parseProdPage(self, response):
    catId = response.css...
    url = 'https://www.expert.fi/Umbraco/Api/Product/ProductsByCategory'

    data = dict()
    ...
    jsonDict = json.dumps(data)

    heads = dict()
    heads['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    heads['Content-Length'] = len(jsonDict)
    heads['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    heads['Referer'] = response.url

    return Request(url=url, method="POST", body=jsonDict, headers=heads, callback=self.startItemProc)

def startItemProc(self, response):
    resDict = json.loads(response.body)

    item = dict()
    for it in resDict['Products']:
        # Product data
        ...
        item['Category Path'] = it['Breadcrumb'][-1]['Name'] + ''.join([' > ' + crumb['Name']
                                                                for crumb in it['Breadcrumb'][-2::-1]])
        # Make the new request for delivery price
        url = 'https://www.expert.fi/Umbraco/Api/Cart/GetFreightOptionsForProduct'
        data = dict()
        ...
        jsonDict = json.dumps(data)

        heads = dict()
        heads['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        heads['Content-Length'] = len(jsonDict)
        heads['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        heads['Referer'] = item['Product URL']

        req = Request(url=url, method="POST", body=jsonDict, headers=heads, callback=self.finishItemProc)
        req.meta['item'] = item
        yield req

def finishItemProc(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    ansList = json.loads(response.body)
    for delivery in ansList:
        if delivery['Name'] == ...
            item['Delivery price'] = delivery['Price']
    return item
```

The log is:

```
2016-10-09 01:11:16 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 9,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 8,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 106652,
 'downloader/request_count': 263,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 263,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5644786,
 'downloader/response_count': 254,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 252,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 19,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 8, 22, 11, 16, 949472),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 265,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 252,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 263,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 263,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 263,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 263,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 8, 22, 7, 7, 811163)}
2016-10-09 01:11:16 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: As far as I understand now, the problem is in calling one methods from another ones with something like `self.myMethodName(response)` - that doesn't work at all. But why and how can I do what I need to do avoiding simple subtitution of one method`s code in another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request returned by the `parseProdPage` method is not used inside the `parseCat` method. You should start by *yielding* that: `yield self.parseProdPage(response)`

Also, you probably want to set `dont_filter=True` in that same request, otherwise most of them will be filtered out (because all of them have the same URL).

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but you're not right. The request can be `return`ed or `yield`ed - both of these work, but of course the method which uses return can return only one request. I've now done the working version of the script. The problem is really in `self.parseProdPage(response)` call in `parseCat` method. It doesn't work. The `yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parseProdPage, dont_filter=True)` instead works just fine, but I don`t like making one more duplicate request.

Comment: That's what I meant, the line which only contains `self.parseProdPage(response)` inside the `parseCat` method has no effect, because that request is not returned/yielded. But I suggested yielding it because if you returned it Python would complain about a "return with value inside a generator" (you are already yielding other requests there)

Comment: Yeah, we are talking about the same, but I just have to mention that, as far as I remember, `yield self.parseProdPage(response)` doesn't work - you should really make a new request by `yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parseProdPage, dont_filter=True)`.

Comment: The result will be the same, but there's a difference on the way the crawling is done. If you just do `yield self.parseProdPage(response)` the spider will yield whatever the result of `parseProdPage` applied to the current response. If you yield a new request with `yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parseProdPage, dont_filter=True)` the same response will be downloaded again and handled by the same method. There's no need to schedule a new request if you already have the response, you could use `parseProdPage` as a regular python method, not a callback.

Comment: Also, I think `yield self.parseProdPage(response)` is not working for you because the request returned by `parseProdPage` does not have `dont_filter=True`, and thus it gets filtered.